# How to save a checkboxed values to ManyToManyField in django with a through relationship?

Tags: django, forms, python-2.7, checkbox, django-views

I'm currently working on a fairly simple django project and could use some help.Currently I am stuck on saving form using checkboxes.

I have the following models with a ManyToMany and through relationship:

```
class ProfileMatch(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,unique=True)
     profiles = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "Profile id: %s" %(self.user.id)
```

I created a HTML form for this with checkbox .Selected profiles_id should save with associate user_id

```
<form action="." method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Select</th>
                                    <th>Profile-ID</th>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                     {% for user in userprofiles %}
                                   <tr>
                                        <label class="checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="user" data-toggle="checkbox" value="{{ user.pk }}">
                                        </label>
                                        <td>{{ user.profile_id }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}    

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                             <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Add Selected </button>
                            </form>
```

And a simple view to save the form:

```
def PremuiumUserProfileSelectList(request, pk):
    match = ProfileMatch.objects.get(pk=pk)


     if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.getlist("user", None):
           checked = request.POST.getlist("user", None)
           premium_user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
           m = match(user=premium_user, profiles=checked)
           m.save()

       else:
          return render(request, "premiumuser/selected_list.html", context)
    else:
         return render(request, "premiumuser/selected_list.html", context)
```

This doesn't saves the form.Form fields were rendered and all selected profiles_id's are showing in a list .How do I save this Form ?I want to save all selected checkbox values in associated user.How do I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do, assuming `checked` is list of ids.

```
match.profiles.add(*checked)
```

Comment: How will I create a match object if ProfileMatch matching query does not exist.?

Comment: `ProfileMatch.objects.create(user=user)`.Then add manytomany field, since object has to be created first before adding related objects.